# Dataframes Aggregate Account and Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe of monetary transcations. Each transaction has a datetime and an account number. I want to aggregate the data and create two new columns:
1. the number of transactions that account has had in the calendar day before the date of the transaction
2. the sum of transactions in the in the calendar day before the date of the transaction

Is there a better way to do this than iterating line by line grouping by account and filtering by date?

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Acc_num | Date_time        | Amount|Tr_count |Sum_tr  | 
---------------------------------------------------------
| 22      | 2018/01/04 14:55 |  10   |0        |0       |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 22      | 2018/01/04 18:00 |  14   |0        |0       |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 22      | 2018/01/05 10:01 |  5    |2        |24      |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 44      | 2018/01/05 08:55 |  100  |0        |0       |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 22      | 2018/01/06 11:55 |  1.2  |1        |5       |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 44      | 2018/01/06 15:05 |  12   |1        |100     |
```

Comment: No need to iterate. You can use a TimeGrouper or you could resample.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the mock table into the question instead of the image?

Comment: @HarvIpan, done